# Dynamically resizable partition in a file.. possible?

Tags: ext4, ecryptfs

I ran into the `ecryptfs` [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/344878) where files with long filenames don't get written (because of the prefix that ecryptfs adds to the original filenames, thus extending their length). So I was wondering if there was a way to create a filesystem (hopefully `ext4`) in a file, inside an ecryptfs mount. Thus, ecryptfs encrypts the file without filename length trouble. However, I don't want to specify a static size for the ext4 filesystem, I want it to grow (or shrink) as I add (or remove) files. I have a feeling this isn't possible, but is there a solution to this problem? I cannot change the filenames that are too long.

Comment: You can read up on [LUKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup)/[cryptsetup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt#cryptsetup) and [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)). Maybe they can help you solve your problem in a different way.

Comment: Are you using filename encryption? Do you have a link for that bug? I don't think any regular filesystems (meant for a partition and useable in a container file) can dynamically resize themselves. That's one of the big advantages to a system like eCryptfs or EncFS, they only take up a little more space than the files themselves.

Comment: @Xen2050 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/344878

Comment: How much more filename characters do you need? [EncFS](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/encfs.1.html) might give you about 50 more (about 190 total, if your host filesystem limit is 256)

Answer (score 3):

As @Lucas mentioned, LUKS would be preferable to eCryptfs for this, but yes, you can rather easily resize an ext4 image file.  You can use `truncate -s xxx file` to change the size of the file, then `losetup -c /dev/loopX` to refresh the loop driver's idea of its size ( or unmount and remount it ), then `resize2fs` to grow it.  To shrink, it must be unmounted and you `resize2fs` prior to reducing the size of the file.  Just be careful you don't shrink the file smaller than `resize2fs` set the size of the filesystem to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I am looking for something that can "dynamically" resize the partition, in other words, it resizes automatically as I add more files, like shrinkwrap.

Comment: @insaner, you either have to live with the name limits of eCryptfs, or manually resize a proper filesystem when you need to adjust your free space.